# Certain websites not displaying correctly in chromium (ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE for all images and css)

Tags: 16.04, chromium, websites, css

I installed ubuntu 16.04 several weeks ago.  Recently (in the past few days), several websites have started displaying incorrectly, i.e. without images or CSS stylings.

For example, here is nytimes.com:

[image: nytimes]

Output from `chromium-browser --version`:

```
Using PPAPI flash.
Chromium 53.0.2785.143 Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 16.04
```

What should I do to fix this?  I tried clearing cookies and disabling all extensions, but the problem persisted.

I have the same problem on certain other websites (e.g. wellsfargo.com), but not all (e.g. askubuntu.com displays correctly). On wellsfargo.com, I see the same sort of `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE` messages in the developer tools console.

This problem does not appear when I use firefox -- it only affects chromium.

Edit:  I uninstalled chromium, rebooted my machine and reinstalled chromium, and the problem persists...

Edit:  on both nytimes.com and wellsfargo.com I see `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE` not only for images but also for the page's css, which explains the lack of stylings.  On wellsfargo.com, for example, `GET https://www01.wellsfargomedia.com/css/home/homepage.css` fails with `net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`.

Edit: amazon.com displays the same problem (no images or css).  Amazon.fr does not load -- instead, I get a warning page from chrome:

> Your connection is not private
>
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from www.amazon.fr
>   (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards).
>   NET::ERR_CERTIFICATE_TRANSPARENCY_REQUIRED
>
> www.amazon.fr normally uses encryption to protect your information.
>   When Chromium tried to connect to www.amazon.fr this time, the website
>   sent back unusual and incorrect credentials. This may happen when an
>   attacker is trying to pretend to be www.amazon.fr, or a Wi-Fi sign-in
>   screen has interrupted the connection. Your information is still
>   secure because Chromium stopped the connection before any data was
>   exchanged.
>
> You cannot visit www.amazon.fr right now because the website uses
>   HSTS. Network errors and attacks are usually temporary, so this page
>   will probably work later.

Comment: Do you experience the same issue with regular Chrome? Are you using OpenDNS by any chance?

Comment: @AndroidDev I installed google-chrome-stable (Google Chrome 54.0.2840.100) to check -- no, I do not experience the issue with regular chrome (I checked nytimes.com and wellsfargo.com).  I don't know what OpenDNS is so I assume I am not using it (unless it is part of ubuntu 16.04 by default)

Comment: Note that uninstalling a program and reinstalling it does _not_ reset its settings (unlike Windows). All it does is to reinstall the program, which does nothing unless the program itself was initially corrupt. To reset your settings, you need to delete them; in the case of Chromium, you simply delete the following folder within your home folder (note the leading dot): `.config/chromium`

Answer (score 11):

It's a known bug:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1641380
- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=664177

The bug has been squashed upstream, and they say that "the updated package should be released soon".

Edit to update status "This bug was fixed in the package chromium-browser - 53.0.2785.143-0ubuntu0.14.04.1.1145" (source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1641380)

Comment: I installed an update today (Nov 17 2016) -- I now have `Chromium 53.0.2785.143 Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 16.04` and nytimes.com, amazon.com et cetera load correctly.

Comment: I just uninstalled and then installed 53.0.2785.143 and amazon.com still does not load for me.  I disabled all off my extensions and then tried again, and it still did not work.

Comment: I installed the `google-chrome-stable` package and updated it. Then in the google chrome app I restarted it by visiting `chrome://restart` and then assets were able to be loaded securely.