# Ubuntu 16.04 Chrome browser blocks many assets from loading

Tags: chromium

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 and Chromium but certain sites do not show up properly or are even marked insecure. `amazon.com` shows up as insecure and Chrome warns me to go back, `outlook.office365.com` only shows a white page with absolutely nothing on it. All of these sites work perfectly fine on Firefox though so I imagine it has something to do with Chromium. What could be the issue?

Comment: This is answered at this AskUbuntu question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/849450/certain-websites-not-displaying-correctly-in-chromium-err-insecure-response-for